# How can i retrieve Deposit in Quickbooks online using API

Tags: quickbooks

We are unable to retrieve Deposit, Transactions, Statement and Transfers using Quickbooks online API.

Environment: C#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To help you, we need to see what you have tried, the specific nature of what "doesn't work", and more about your environment.  Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and edit your question so we are more willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the QBO Entity docs.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference

What do you mean by 'unable to retrieve' ? Are you getting any exception ? In that case, please mention the details in your post.

You can try all QBO Endpoints using APIExplorer tool.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

You can try the sample .net application as well.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-DotNet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the deposit from the QBO using the below script:

```
QueryService<Deposit> DepositQueryService = new QueryService<Deposit>(context);
var ListDeposit = DepositQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Deposit MaxResults 1000").ToList();
```

This will help you.